# Why is this layout broken in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

This site: http://www.whsc.ie/ uses a jquery lightbox style plugin which seems to be breaking the layout in Google's Chrome Browser. When viewed in Chrome, the header of the site is about 30 pixels taller than it should be.

When inspecting the source elements it appears to be caused by some hidden elements that are used by the colorbox jQuery plugin.

I've tried everything I can think of to figure this out and fix the problem but to no avail.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: on my computer it looks the same (in chrome and ff4)

Comment: I looked at it in Chrome, Firefox and IE and it looks the same. Please explain what's different in more detail.

Comment: What browser versions are you using, and what browser renders this as you think it should?

Comment: @AlexJillard: And you forgot to ask what version.

Comment: Not seeing it - looked at it in Chrome 11, Firefox 3.6, Safari 5 and IE 8 on Win 7 and height of the header is same all around, everything else within pixels of each other (normal differences). Can you provide some links to screen shots?

Comment: @the_drow: No, I asked what versions he was using...unless you mean version of the "correctly" rendering browser?

Comment: Looks good in Chrome to me. It looks like you're using Wordpress. I bet you're logged in and the logged in styles are messing with your layout. Try logging out to see if it displays properly.

Comment: are you talking about the space between the menu and the content box? if so that is caused by margin-top:10px; by css class .contentContainer

Answer (score 0):

My Bad!

It seems it's actually a Wordpress bug that only appears when a user is logged in. I kept seeing it on the browsers on my own machine because they were all logged in, but when I went to a different machine the bug wasn't visble.

Thanks for the replies though, much appreciated.